# IPad + UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am facing one weird issue with UIPickerview in IPad. I am not able to select the last row by making use of

```
[iPickerView selectRow:11 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

This is picker data source

```
  iPickerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"1:00", 
                        @"2:00",
                        @"3:00", 
                        @"4:00", 
                        @"5:00", 
                        @"6:00",
                        @"7:00",
                        @"8:00",
                        @"9:00",
                        @"10:00",
                        @"11:00",
                        @"12:00", 
                        nil];
```

AND

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
  if (component == 0)
   return [iPickerArray count];
}
```

Whenever I issue this request

```
  [iPickerView selectRow:11 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

It always select 11.00 :( and for other it works proper

Please help me,if I am doing something wrong over here !!!!!

Comment: What's your `-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`?

Comment: its 

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 NSString *returnStr = @"";
 
 if (pickerView == iPickerView) {
  if (component == 0) {
   returnStr = [iPickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
  }
  else {
      if (row == 0)
        return @"AM";
      return @"PM";
  }
 }
 
 return returnStr;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[iPickerView selectRow:12 inComponent:1 animated:NO];
```